# Downloadable pdf format of GRASSGIS 7.0 manual

Tags: postgresql, grass-gis

Can anyone help with a link or something that could enable the download of a pdf version of the grassgis manual? I am having a hard time trying to convert the html version into printable pdf.
Nkeze

Comment: Well i got something and it's working... sorry if i disturbed.